# how to restore mysql backup that have generated always as column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
CREATE TABLE `revenue_daily` ( `wallet` varbinary(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`tc_access` varbinary(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`tc_short` varbinary(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`total_toll_collection` varbinary(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (`wallet` + `tc_access`) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
`cash_collection` varbinary(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (`total_toll_collection` - `tc_short`) VIRTUAL NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii;
```

That table has generated column.I backed up database structure with data and when i am restoring same .sql file then error occur.
Error is:-

```
ERROR 3105 (HY000) at line 262: The value specified for generated column 'total_toll_collection' in table 'revenue_daily' is not allowed.
```

I am using mysql version:-

```
sunilp@sunilp ~> mysql --version
mysql: [Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d mysqld.cnf' is ignored.
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Comment: It should work automatically. The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) says that if you have generated columns you need to use the version of `mysqldump` from MySQL 5.7.9 or higher, because earlier versions have a bug.

Comment: What does `mysqldump --version` say?

Comment: sunilp@sunilp ~> mysqldump --version
    mysqldump: [Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf' is ignored.
    mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.7.18, for Linux (x86_64)

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't ignore those warnings about the permissions of `mysqld.cnf`.

Comment: Are you sure you were using this version when you made the backup? What does the first ;line of the `.sql` file say?

Comment: I resolve this error:-by this command : sudo chmod 600 /etc/mysql/my.cnf  But same error :-ERROR 3105 (HY000) at line 262: The value specified for generated column 'total_toll_collection' in table 'revenue_daily' is not allowed.

Comment: What version of mysql did the dump come from and what version of mysql are you trying to restore to. I have tried this on mysql version 14.4 Distrib 5.7.18 for linux with mysqldump ver 10.13 Distrib 5.7.18 for linux and it works fine.

Comment: The permission warning has nothing to do with this error. What does the first line of the dump file say?

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/240882/how-to-take-mysqldump-with-generated-column/

Answer (score 8):

This is a problem when using mysqldump from MariaDB with virtual generated columns.
MariaDB's mysqldump apparently dumps the generated values, but MySQL only accepts `DEFAULT` as value for a virtual generated column.

It seems like you need to use MySQL's mysqldump to correctly dump and restore virtual generated columns on a MySQL server.

The bug was also reported [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79148).

---

What I do as a workaround, is replace the virtual column in the dump:

```
sed -i 's/GENERATED ALWAYS AS .* VIRTUAL/NOT NULL/' mydump.sql
```

then restore the dump, then drop/add the generated column again:

```
mysql -e "ALTER TABLE foo DROP COLUMN bar;\
ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN bar VARCHAR(255) AS ...;"
```

---

I also posted this answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/279248/163392).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem dumping it from mariadb using adminer (https://www.adminer.org/)

In my case I solved it doing dump with phpmyadmin. It worked for me.

I don't know reason but adminer dump generated values columns. It shouldn't because that value should be generated when rows are inserted.

I didn't try what happens when using mysqldump from command line...

Answer (score 0):

We managed to do it by splitting the main `mysqldump` command into steps :

- Drop all tables (if you are not already using the `--add-drop-database`       parameter in your original `mysqldump` command)
- Add the parameter `--ignore-table=your_schema.your_table` to your original `mysqldump` command
- After this one ran, use a new `mysqldump` command to create only the table structure :

  ```
  mysqldump --no-data ... your_schema your_table
  ```
- Use a `mysql` command to run the proper `ALTER` on your_table (you want to change the type for a basic one) for example :

  ```
  mysql ... -D your_schema -e "ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY COLUMN your_column1 boolean default null, MODIFY COLUMN your_column2 boolean default null;"
  ```
- Finally, use a `mysqldump` command to only fill the table (not create it) :

  ```
  mysqldump --no-create-info ... -e your_schema your_table
  ```

Hope it helps, have a great day !