# Issues in export and import generated stored/virtual column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, adminer

I have a database with set of generated stored columns. When i exporting the database, the sql file comes with the generated column also. I'm using the adminer as the mysql client. Now the problem is import section. If i try to import that sql file, it gives such errors like

```
The value specified for generated column 'field_name' in table 'table_name' is not allowed.
```

Table creation

```
  CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
      `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `field_name` text,
    `generated_field` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT('hello ', `field_name`)) STORED
    );
```

Error thrown query is

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`id`, `field_name`, `generated_field`) VALUES (1, 'James', 'hello James')
```

I got the solution by using a simple way. Just i removed the generated column from insert query. **Now it's working**. Because the generated column only used for gettin the data from the mysql server

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`id`, `field_name`) VALUES (1, 'James')
```

*****But what is the exact solution for gettin the clear export file for import it to the sql  server without any errors**

Because this is too difficult for the large sql data set

Comment: I am looking for a solution for exactly the same problem. Did you manage to solve it already?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to restore mysql backup that have generated always as column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46127855/how-to-restore-mysql-backup-that-have-generated-always-as-column)

Comment: i found it, adminer is taking the generated columns while we exporting the SQL. and we don't need that. it's automatically happen by the insert query. so I suggest to use the phpmyadmin for getting the clear SQL export without generated data